# Converting between IVector<T>^ and C-style array of bytes in a winrt component

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

My universal store project for windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 (C#) uses a windows runtime component (C++) that consists of a C library and a C++/CX wrapper class that provides access to C code for winrt environment.

I pass arrays of bytes from C# code to the component and get arrays of bytes back using `IVector<unsigned char>^` interface. So, I need to convert back and forth between `IVector` and C-style array of `unsigned char`.

This is how I do that now:

```
unsigned char *Component::CopyToArray(IVector<unsigned char>^ source)
{
    unsigned char *target = new unsigned char[source->Size];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < source->Size; i++) {
        target[i] = source->GetAt(i);
    }
    return target;
}

Vector<unsigned char>^ Component::CopyToVector(unsigned char *source, unsigned int length)
{
    Vector<unsigned char>^ target = ref new Vector<unsigned char>();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        target->Append(source[i]);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid allocating memory and copying data?

**UPDATE**: I realized `CopyToVector` is obsolete, because there's a constructor that takes a pointer.

```
ref new Vector<unsigned char>(pointer, size)
```

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

I changed code to use `const Platform::Array<unsigned char>^` for parameter types and `Platform::Array<unsigned char>^` for return types of public api of C++ wrapper class. C# sees these types as `byte[]`, so there's no need for explicit conversion. And in C++ `unsigned char *` pointer is accessible as simple as `argOfArrayType->Data`. To return data from C++ to C# I use `ref new Array<unsigned char>(pointer, size)`.

Comment: I wonder if anyone can oath that there is no memory copying when converting from byte[] to Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with C++/CX is limited to a couple of apps, but why not use [Platform::WriteOnlyArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441551.aspx) instead of the vector? With the array you can access the data directly through the `Data` property. So the C# -> C++/CX direction can be optimized that way. It also has a `Array(T* data, unsigned int size)` constructor that should help in the C++/CX -> C# direction. However I'm not sure about the memory management in this case, if the array wraps or copies the data. And if it does wrap it, how does it know how to free it?

Comment: Thanks Rudolfs. I'll look at the issue for some more time and update the question on the results. Btw, I realized that `CopyToVector()` is completely obsolete because we can do just `ref new Vector<unsigned char>(pointer, size);`

Comment: @NoxNoctis true, but as far as I know, you can't get continuous memory pointer from `Vector`, that is why imho `Array` is better:)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try to replace vectors with arrays. Just not certain it will work fine when crossing abi boundary.